# AWS Organisational Units

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been tasked with setting up AWS for my company as we're planning on migrating over if all goes well.  I created users and built a test EC2 instance, but I did not count for a dev and live environments. I did some research and found OU is the best thing to do to separate Live and Dev environments. If I create a Dev OU, can I move over the users, policies, ec2 instances etc over to new OU?

I tried to search this on Google but came up short.

Comment: One of the option is to leverage Infrastructure as a code pattern by using Terraform for example. It allows you to easily manage AWS resources in multiple AWS accounts without clicking them via AWS Console.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the "AWS Organizations" service, OUs you create in there are used to organize multiple AWS accounts within the same AWS Organization.

Through the AWS Organizations service you can apply SCP policies and enforce certain settings to your AWS accounts (e.g., tags, services to be enables, etc.). However, IAM users, roles, groups, and policies will still be stored within each AWS account and should be managed in the AWS accounts themselves.

So, to answer your question:

> If I create a Dev OU, can I move over the users, policies, ec2 instances etc over to new OU?

No, you can't, as they need to be created within each AWS account.

To perform the environment separation (Prod, Dev, QA, etc) you could leverage the AWS multi-account strategy. This is a best-practice based on the [AWS Well-Architected Framework](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/organizing-your-aws-environment/organizing-your-aws-environment.html) that might be useful for your scenario.

Furthermore, I advise you to take a look at the [AWS Organizations service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_introduction.html) and how to get started with [multi-account management](https://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/accounts/latest/reference/accounts-welcome.html) documentation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your post. I have been looking into/reading the guides this week and I'm still stuck. Would I need AWS Control Tower if I were to also implement something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hZWPkIZxPw

Comment: Hi, @SB8767 , sorry for the late reply. Somehow this message has slipped me. So, whether to use AWS Control Tower or not is up to you. Control Tower is a nice tool to automate account creation in a consistent and automated way, but there are other tools that you can use to achieve the same, such as Terraform or Mesh Cloud. Either way, you don't have to use any of these tools alongside AWS Organizations. It means, technically, you can still have AWS Organizations even when all your accounts are manually created.